# Spring integration websocket throws " 'outputChannel' or 'outputChannelName' is required " Exception

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-integration, spring-websocket

I'm new to Spring integration framework.
While running the spring integration websocket sample [code](https://spring.io/blog/2014/11/15/building-a-spring-integration-4-1-websocket-endpoint) I'm getting 
***'outputChannel' or 'outputChannelName' is required*** exception.

Did I missed something ?

Following is my code,

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@RestController
public class Application {

    public static void main(String args[]) throws Throwable {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }

    @Bean
    ServerWebSocketContainer serverWebSocketContainer() {
        return new ServerWebSocketContainer("/names").withSockJs();
    }

    @Bean
    MessageHandler webSocketOutboundAdapter() {
        return new WebSocketOutboundMessageHandler(serverWebSocketContainer());
    }

    @Bean(name = "webSocketFlow.input")
    MessageChannel requestChannel() {
        return new DirectChannel();
    }

    @Bean
    IntegrationFlow webSocketFlow() {
        return f -> {
            Function<Message, Object> splitter = m -> serverWebSocketContainer().getSessions().keySet().stream()
                    .map(s -> MessageBuilder.fromMessage(m).setHeader(SimpMessageHeaderAccessor.SESSION_ID_HEADER, s).build()).collect(Collectors.toList());
            f.split(Message.class, splitter).channel(c -> c.executor(Executors.newCachedThreadPool())).handle(webSocketOutboundAdapter());
        };
    }

    @RequestMapping("/hi/{name}")
    public void send(@PathVariable String name) {
        requestChannel().send(MessageBuilder.withPayload(name).build());
    }
}
```

Exception stack,

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: 'outputChannel' or 'outputChannelName' is required
    at org.springframework.util.Assert.state(Assert.java:70)
    at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.MessageProducerSupport.afterSingletonsInstantiated(MessageProducerSupport.java:153)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:781)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:867)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: 'outputChannel' or 'outputChannelName' is required
at org.springframework.util.Assert.state(Assert.java:70)
at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.MessageProducerSupport.afterSingletonsInstantiated(MessageProducerSupport.java:153)
```

Pay attention - `MessageProducerSupport`. Your code doesn't show any kind of that, so you just hide something in your application from us.

And I guess you might have something like:

```
@Bean
public WebSocketInboundChannelAdapter webSocketInboundChannelAdapter() {
    ...
}
```

And exactly this one must be declare with the `setOutputChannel()`.

Or if you use it as a starting point from Java DSL - `IntegrationFlows.from(webSocketInboundChannelAdapter())`, - then don't declare it with the `@Bean`. The Framework will take care about the proper configuration and registration for you afterwards.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your support.
 As you said there was a config class with the WebSocketInboundChannelAdapter bean definition.
 I was trying to build a Source App for cloud stream starters, where I'm very much new, because websocket source is not available on github.
I want to start a websocket server as source and pass the messages received to the broker (Kafka/rabit). I want to know what is handled by the framework and what we need to write in the Source part. Can you give me a brief?

Comment: Well, that deserves a separate SO question. Not related to your current one. However we could discuss it in the appropriate GH issue: https://github.com/spring-cloud-stream-app-starters/websocket/issues/2. And you should consider to accept my answer here if it is sufficient for the mentioned problem

Comment: I have created a new SO question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47175066/how-to-create-a-custom-source-app-for-spring-cloud-stream-app-starters-project