# How to create a custom source app for spring-cloud-stream-app-starters project

Tags: spring-boot, websocket, spring-integration, spring-websocket, spring-cloud-stream

I want to create a web-socket source (for **spring-cloud-stream-app-starters**) which is currently not available on git hub.

I went through some of the available sources but had some confusions, may be because I'm not familiar with the framework.

Can I just create a spring boot application with `Source binding` and  return the received packets from web-socket clients in an `@InboundChannelAdapter(value = Source.OUTPUT)` annotated method. ?
Also how can I use **WebSocketInboundChannelAdapter** to start a websocket server and push the packets to the underlying broker.?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get some ideas in the [Reference Manual](https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-stream-app-starters/docs/Celsius.RC1/reference/html/).

The `WebSocketInboundChannelAdapter` is an event-driven channel adapter, it's not pollable source. So, what you need is just a `@Bean` for this one and an appropriate reference to the `Source.OUTPUT`.

The `WebSocketInboundChannelAdapter` doesn't start server. That is responsibility of the:

```
/**
 * The {@link IntegrationWebSocketContainer} implementation for the {@code server}
 * {@link org.springframework.web.socket.WebSocketHandler} registration.
 * <p>
 * Registers an internal {@code IntegrationWebSocketContainer.IntegrationWebSocketHandler}
 * for provided {@link #paths} with the {@link WebSocketHandlerRegistry}.
 * <p>
 * The real registration is based on Spring Web-Socket infrastructure via {@link WebSocketConfigurer}
 * implementation of this class.
 *
 * @author Artem Bilan
 * @author Gary Russell
 * @since 4.1
 */
public class ServerWebSocketContainer extends IntegrationWebSocketContainer
        implements WebSocketConfigurer, SmartLifecycle {
```

We have a [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/4.3.12.RELEASE/reference/html/web-sockets.html) on the matter as well.

There is also a [stomp-chat](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration-samples/tree/master/applications/stomp-chat) sample to demonstrate the server behavior.

I think you don't need "underlying broker" in this kind of `source` application: you just receive messages over web socket and publish them to the `Source.OUTPUT`. Why do you need STOMP broker here?

**UPDATE**

Have just tested this code against Rabbit Binder:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableBinding(Source.class)
public class CloudStreamWebSocketSourceApplication {

    @Bean
    public WebSocketInboundChannelAdapter webSocketInboundChannelAdapter() {
        WebSocketInboundChannelAdapter webSocketInboundChannelAdapter =
                new WebSocketInboundChannelAdapter(serverWebSocketContainer());
        webSocketInboundChannelAdapter.setOutputChannelName(Source.OUTPUT);
        return webSocketInboundChannelAdapter;
    }

    @Bean
    public IntegrationWebSocketContainer serverWebSocketContainer() {
        return new ServerWebSocketContainer("/test")
                .withSockJs()
                .setAllowedOrigins("*");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        SpringApplication.run(CloudStreamWebSocketSourceApplication.class, args);
        System.out.println("Done");
    }

}
```

My test-case is like:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
public class CloudStreamWebSocketSourceApplicationTests {

    @LocalServerPort
    private String port;

    @Test
    public void testWebSocketStreamSource() throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        StandardWebSocketClient webSocketClient = new StandardWebSocketClient();

        ClientWebSocketContainer clientWebSocketContainer =
                new ClientWebSocketContainer(webSocketClient, "ws://localhost:" + this.port + "/test/websocket");
        clientWebSocketContainer.start();

        WebSocketSession session = clientWebSocketContainer.getSession(null);

        session.sendMessage(new TextMessage("foo"));

        Thread.sleep(10000);
    }

}
```

This is my dependencies:

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-stream-rabbit</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-integration</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-websocket</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.integration</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-integration-websocket</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Comment: Thank you @Artem Bilan. Yes, you are correct I don't need a broker here just confused with Broker and Middleware.

Comment: Just for more clarity. So for the WS Server just the 3 beans will do the job?
(ServerWebSocketContainer, WebSocketInboundChannelAdapter and MessageChannel)

Comment: You don't need `MessageChannel` bean. You have there just `WebSocketInboundChannelAdapter.setOutputChannelName(Source.OUTPUT)`. The real channel is created by the Binder automatically. Although you can inject `Source` in your `@Configuraiton` and use its `output()` to configure `WebSocketInboundChannelAdapter`

Comment: Ok, tats cool.
But do I need any specific anotations (other than EnableWebSocket) to start the WS server. Because my code doesn't start the WS Server.

Comment: The `EnableWebSocket` is enabled by the Spring Integration automatically. You might just don't have particular dependencies in your classpath. I guess `spring-boot-starter-websocket` is your best friend.

Comment: See an UPDATE in my answser

Comment: Thanks for your kind support. This works like a charm. But in the client test why are you providing a random port ? Does it do the magic of finding the server random port and connect to it or a typo ? :)

Comment: That’s correct way to go when you may have conflicts with an existing services or other tests on CI. See Boot documentation for more info

Answer (score 2):

@Krishas I would definitely look at the available *sources*, find the one that closely resembles what you're trying to accomplish and model your new source after it. 
In general what you are suggesting is correct. . . it should be Spring boot app annotated with `@Source`. But of course the devil is in the details. So what I would suggest is to create a PR so we can all review it and help you bring it to the state where we can include it in the pool of available starters.

Comment: Also see my answer.

Comment: Thank you Oleg Zhurakousky.

Comment: https://github.com/spring-cloud-stream-app-starters/websocket/pull/3 Please have a look at the PR.